# How to find the whole X and Y coordinates of the text?

Tags: android, textview

I'm developing a kids alphabets learning application. I need to get the X and Y coordinates of the whole text area from a textview to allow them to draw over the text only.  For Example: I have a letter A in my text view, I need to allow the user to draw the letter only over the A text only and need to block the drawing outside the text.

My only problem is I don't know how to find the text area for alphabets as I have increased the font size for the text to display bigger and center aligned it in the screen.

Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: Using [PorterDuff](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode) might help to clear and show based on content of canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15B3L78jWfI)?

To stop user from drawing outside of the given area, overriding (12:22) onTouchEvent() you could just put a clause checking whether the given coordinates are inside, or not.

To check if they are inside, you could write such a simple function:

```
int MIN_X;
int MAX_X;
int MIN_Y;
int MAX_Y;

boolean isInside(int xCord, int yCord){

    if(xCord>=MIN_X && xCord<=MAX_X && yCord>=MIN_Y && yCord<=MAX_Y)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

You'd only have to override the min and max values, each time the chosen area changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I too have the same idea to avoid drawing outside the text area but how can I identify whether the user touched x and y coordinates are inside the text area or not?

Comment: I couldn't find any methods from textview to  get the min x, miny, max x,max y?  Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Use textView.getX(), getY(), getWidth() and getHeight() to determine bounds.

Comment: Sorry. This is not working. It allows me to draw below the text area.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below mentioned code:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = textView.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
@Override 
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); 
     // Initialize a new integer array two hold the TextView x y position
            int[] location = new int[2];

            textView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

}
```

});

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Already I was able to get the x and y coordinates. My only problem is how to identify the whole text area to compare it with the x and y coordinates of the user touched area ?